# Windows Path Variable - Two folders match DLL - Which Is Picked First

Tags: c#, windows

For one reason or another I have a PATH variable which has multiple entries where my exe can be located.

I am struggling to find the order that Windows uses when resolving DLLS.

Does it scan the Path variable and the first (in the list) match is used?  In my testing it looks like the final one is used.

Does anyone know what the behaviour of this is and whether it is documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the last one that is read wins.

Comment: Its what the testing suggests - But is there any link which documents that?

Comment: Interesting that this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586(VS.85).aspx claims that directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable- But it does not say whether it starts at beginning or backwards or how

Answer (score 1):

For .NET, I don't think that the PATH is used. [Here](http://kalpeshshirodker.wordpress.com/2007/09/06/specify-where-to-look-for-referenced-assemblies-in-c-application/) is an article that explains CLR probing in more detail.

EDIT:

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164080.aspx#S5) a better article from MSDN.

Also [this](http://en.csharp-online.net/.NET_CLR_Components%E2%80%94Resolving_Names_to_Locations) article has a nice flowchart that explains some of the assembly loading logic.